# Register VS Code snippets as part of NPM package

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In an effort to encourage standard coding practices on my team I would like to share a set of code snippets.  This is very easy to do for a single project/workspace (via `.vscode/xyz.code-snippets`), but I would like to be able to share the same snippets across multiple projects/workspaces.

Since these are JS/Node projects we have a collection of custom NPM packages and I would like to manage these snippets in an NPM package as well.

Is there a way to register VS Code snippets contained in an NPM package without requiring the installation of an extension?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `npx` and run a command that fetches different `.code-snippets` for different use cases from a github repo, similar to how `npx tailwind init` would scaffold out a file for customising `tailwindcss`

Comment: Huh. Interesting!

Comment: would this install the snippets automatically?  and update when a change is made in the repo?

Comment: @StephenRichter No, just like no npm module would. I personally use shell aliases. something like `alias vuedotfiles='aria2c --allow-overwrite raw-github-link & aria2c ...otherdotfiles'` creating necessary directories and installing npm modules in the process.